# WARN -- : MONGODB | Unsupported client option 'raise_not_found_error'. It will be ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, mlab, mongoid6

I need to setup option in mongoid.yml. It work in development but production in heroku gave the ignore warning message.
Is anyone experience and how to fix this ?

```
W, [2017-04-05T02:04:09.447207 #4]  WARN -- : MONGODB | Unsupported client option 'raise_not_found_error'. It will be ignored.
W, [2017-04-05T02:04:09.449089 #4]  WARN -- : MONGODB | Unsupported client option 'belongs_to_required_by_default'. It will be ignored.
W, [2017-04-05T02:04:09.449176 #4]  WARN -- : MONGODB | Unsupported client option 'consistency'. It will be ignored.
```

In mongoid.yml

```
production:
  clients:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGODB_URI'] %>
      options:
        raise_not_found_error: false
        belongs_to_required_by_default: false
        consistency: :strong
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the error Mongo db gives when it tries to find any record and it doesn't match in database. In order to resolve this

Add this line in your production configuration
**raise_not_found_error: false**

```
mongoid.yml
production:
  clients:
    default:
      database: database_name
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        read:
          mode: :primary
        max_pool_size: 1
        raise_not_found_error: false
```

Comment: I already have "raise_not_found_error: false" that why in WARN at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

`belongs_to_required_by_default` doesn't go under clients > default > options. It should be defined under your environment:

```
production:
  clients:
    default:
      uri: <%= ENV['MONGODB_URI'] %>            
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
    belongs_to_required_by_default: false
```